# PHP DATE logic problems

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

Now I stand in front of logig proplem ... how do I put it best when I try to spend as Everyday Traffic?

2014-01-26: xx traffic 2014-01-27: xx traffic 2014-01-28: xx traffic

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<?php 

function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2)
{
    $base = log($size) / log(1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'k', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');   

    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}


$db=mysql_connect("localhost","traffic","....."); 
mysql_select_db("traffic",$db);
$qry = "SELECT SUM(bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 
          WHERE SUBSTRING(stamp_updated,9,2) = '28' ";


$select = mysql_query($qry);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($select);


echo 'Summe: '.formatBytes($result['total']);  
//echo $result['total'];


?>
```

HOw do I put it best to me that it calculates all data and gives me back in weekdays

Comment: What does this have to do with dates?

Comment: The date it refers from a column stamp_updated example 2014-01-28. Now I would be happy to spend a weeks edition 


2014-01-26 = Xy Traffic 
2014-01-28 = Xy Traffic 

But I think I have it already get back;)

Comment: Is the stamp_updated field of type _timestamp_?

Comment: stamp_updated is a DATETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Day of date_field` and `group by date_field`

```
$qry = "SELECT stamp_updated, SUM(bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 "
       . " WHERE DAY(stamp_updated) = '28' "
       . " GROUP BY stamp_updated";
```

results records on a day `28`th of all matching dates.